# Use same foreach multiple times

Tags: php, foreach

I'm using a foreach to load the name en contents of a certain product.
In my navigation it has to load the name, further down we need to load the contents but in a slider.. but this is not working?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#content1" data-toggle="tab">Overzicht</a></li>
<?php foreach($projects as $project) : ?>
    <li><a href="tab<?= $project['id'] ?>" data-toggle="tab"><?= $project['name'] ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>

<div id="tabContent" class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="content1">
    Content 1 tab
</div>
<?php foreach($projects as $project) : ?>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab<?= $project['id'] ?>">
    test
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Comment: define "not working". Did you ever try to peek into page source?

Comment: What is "not working"? Did you see an error, or did you see abnormal results? Can you show us what the result is?

Comment: How is this not working? foreach doesnt affect the iterable in any way (unless you want it to), so unless your $projects variable is being modified between both loops i dont see why one would work and the other wouldnt. Try var_dump($projects) in between if you cant find out where it is being modified.

Comment: Seems like you forget to "echo" the content: <?php echo $project['id'] ?>

Comment: By not working i mean the second one is not printing anything. Page source shows blank for the second time i use it.