# Using the same foreach multiple times

Tags: php, foreach

I'm currently working on a php script and stuck at this part. I have a database table which I want to display information from each row. I have two dropdown menus which I want to have the exact same names with just with a different url. I'm assuming this is possible, and I'm doing something wrong, as I'm not that advanced with php.

I found this question that was similar but didn't seem to see anything that helped much.

[Use same foreach multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522616/use-same-foreach-multiple-times)

Here is what I currently have

Top of page

```
<?php
require("common.php"); 

if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
{ 
    header("Location: login.php"); 
    die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
} 

$header = "SELECT id, location FROM table";

try 
{ 
    $headerstmt = $db->prepare($header); 
    $headerstmt->execute();
} 

catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
}
?>
```

Then here is the section with the foreach loops

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="dropdown <?php if ($page == 'view') {echo 'active';} ?>">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">View <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php foreach ($headerstmt->fetchAll() as $hrow) { ?>
        <li><a href="view.php?id=<?php echo $hrow['id'] ?>"><?php echo $hrow['location']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown <?php if ($page == 'edit') {echo 'active';} ?>">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Edit <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php foreach ($headerstmt->fetchAll() as $hrow) { ?>
        <li><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $hrow['id'] ?>"><?php echo $hrow['location']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>                        
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

The first foreach loop works correctly, however the second one is blank.

Thanks in advance if anyone is able help.

Comment: what about storing fetchAll() result in a *variable?*

Comment: @YourCommonSense Never has your username fit any better.

Comment: Perhaps you need to rewind the buffer. There's some solutions to that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823758/how-can-i-rewind-a-pdo-result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the result of `$headerstmt->fetchAll()` in a variable and then use the resulting variable for the foreach loops.

```
$results = $headerstmt->fetchAll();
foreach( $results as $row ) {

}
foreach( $results as $row ) {

}
foreach( $results as $row ) {

}
```